# Event handling in Scala

Tags: scala, actor

What should I use to implement simple event handling in Scala?

I don't want to rely on Scala.Swing APIs and I'm not sure if I should use Actors.

What I need is simple generic over event type handlers and event sources. Concurrency is not a requirement. Aren't Actors too heavy for simple tasks requiring no concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on *Scala Swing* and you only require publishers and observers, why not **roll up your own implementation?** This would amount to 2-3, below-10-line Scala traits (depending on whether you also want event buses or not).

If you don't mind a more complex API (especially since you're getting concurrency handling for free), **you could try out the `Observable`s out of [RxScala](http://rxscala.github.io/)**. Take a look at the aforementioned [`Observable`](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observable), [`Observer`](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observer) and [`Subject`](http://rxscala.github.io/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Subject) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the Akka actor solution was a little bit overkill, so I end up implementing my own event sourcing solution in this open source project.

The persistence layer is a decision for the developer, but I provide practical examples of execution using couchbase.

Take a look in case you consider useful.

https://github.com/politrons/Scalaydrated